# Transform CSS { ul li:hover a } in JQUERY .hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I want to now if there's a way to transform this css properties in a jquery .hover, or control this by javascript to change the colour dynamically.

CSS:

```
ul li:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Can anyone Help ?

**EDIT:**

My problem is:

I have a drop down menu and i want that when I hover the menu the text color change and when I hover the submenu the hover state stays for both.

**JQuery:**

```
$("ul li").hover(function () {          
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "white"}, 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "black"}, 400);
});
```

To animate background color on hover in menu and submenu.

For example if the text are black I want to make the text white on hover. For this I use:(Submenu example, for menu change the selector of course)

```
$('ul.submenu li a').hover(function () {        
    $(this).css({color:'#FFFFFF'});
}, function () {            
    $(this).css({color:'#00FF00'});
});
```

All This works fine, but when I hover the submenu the menu returns to the original state(because the mouseleave is activated on hover out). All I want is that when I hover submenu the hover state in menu stays active as well.

I've tried many things but all give me problems, only thing that works is css, but I need to control the text colours dynamically too.

**HTML Structure:**

```
<ul class="menu">

      <li><a href="#">text</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">text</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>

      <li><a href="#">text</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Isn't the first selector superfluous?

Comment: yes, you're right Sime Vidas, I apologize

Comment: @Sbml So, your `ul.submenu` is not (structurally) located inside the LI elements of the main menu?

Comment: Could you post an example of your HTML?

Comment: The ul.submenu is located inside the li elements. I edit with html structure. Thanks

Comment: Because colors are diferent in the menu and submenu I cannot use for example ul.menu li to goes back to original colors after hover. This is one of my problems in my tests.

Comment: Just an FYI: you're missing an `</li>` at the end.  Please let me know if my answer is along the right path that you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me know if this is along the right track of what you're asking.

I haven't got it working fully, but give this a look and see if it helps:
[my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/LuTsT/)

Here's the code so far:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var sm;                       // submenu
       var delay = 500;              // delay before applying changes
       var tID;                      // timeout id
       var color_on  = '#fff'
         , color_off = '#000';
       var oPrev;


       $('ul.menu > li > a').hover(
          function() {
             if (tID && $(this) === oPrev) {clearTimeout(tID);}
             oPrev = $(this);
             sm  = $(this).next('.submenu');
             if(sm){sm.stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');}
          },
          function() {
             if (tID) {clearTimeout(tID);}
             tID = setTimeout(
                      function() {
                         sm.stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
                      }, delay);
          }
       );

       $('.submenu > li > a').hover(
           function() {
              if (tID) {clearTimeout(tID);}
              oPrev.css('color',color_on);
              $(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
           },
           function() {
              if (tID) {clearTimeout(tID);}
              sm  = $(this);
              tID = setTimeout(
                       function() {
                          oPrev.css('color','');
                          sm.closest('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
                       }, delay);
           }
       );
   });
```

And CSS:

```
   a
   {
       color           : #000;
       text-decoration : none;
   }
   a:hover
   {
       color           : #fff;
   }

   ul li
   {
       background      : orange;
       border          : 1px solid black;
       display         : inline-block;
       padding         : 0 1em;
       vertical-align  : top;  
   }

   .menu
   {
       background      : #ccc;
       border          : 1px solid black;
       display         : inline-block;
       padding         : .25em 1em;
       vertical-align  : top;
   }
   .submenu
   {
       border          : 1px solid black;
       border-width    : 1px 0 0 0;
       display         : none;
   }
   .submenu li
   {  
       background      : red;
       border-width    : 0;
   }
   .submenu li a:hover
   {
       color           : #fff;
   }
```

---

Note: I'm not saying this is the best answer, nor is it a complete solution, but maybe something in here will assist someone in finding the correct solution.

Comment: Hello, yes, I think you understand what I want. Is a strange way of doing it but it could help. I'm still trying to understand somethings in your code :) .One problem in your code is open/close/hover in submenu. This is my implementation of your code http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/ajtdA/4/

Comment: One thing that not works here is, if we hover the submenu and then hover a menu item the color don't change...

Comment: @Sbml: right, as stated, this is incomplete and has bug; this was more of a starting answer that hopefully someone could add to.  This is using a time delay before checking/applying the change, mostly because I was using an animation, but it also works for submenus that aren't nested inside the menu (so the mouseleave event can be canceled).  Using jQuery you can find the ancestor to the submenu and change right before its fadeout event.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("ul li a").hover(function() {
    $(this)
        .data("color", $(this).css("color"))
        .css("color", "#FFF");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("color", $(this).data("color"));
});

$("ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("a")
        .data("color", $(this).css("color"))
        .css("color", "#FFF");
}, function() {
    $(this).find("a").css("color", $(this).data("color"));
});
```

---

**Update:**

Assuming that the first selector (`ul li a:hover`) is superfluous, we can simplify the code considerably:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("a").css("color", "#FFF");
}, function() {
    $(this).find("a").removeAttr("style");
});
```

This updated code should work also (under the condition that you don't have additional CSS code inside the style attribute of the ANCHOR elements).

---

**Update:**

An alternative solution would be this:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover", $(this).is(":hover"));
});
```

with this CSS code:

```
ul li.hover a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**I highly recommend this alternative solution!**

Comment: In this case the toogleClass don't work, i edit my question with a better explanantion, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this (now tested: http://jsfiddle.net/nathan/J7HLV/):

```
$('ul li a, ul li').hover(function () {
  $(this).add($(this).children('a')).filter('a').css('color','#fff');
},function () {
  $(this).add($(this).children('a')).filter('a').css('color','');
});
```

Comment: Would whoever down-voted explain why? It's not very constructive to just down-vote without a comment.

Comment: He wants it to trigger on the `li` as well as the `a`. Plus the `filter('a')` is useless.

Comment: @Josh It does trigger the on the li. And the filter isn't useless, because it gets rid of the li from the collection. Look at the test: http://jsfiddle.net/nathan/J7HLV/

Comment: I missed it triggering, my mistake.

Comment: Don't work for me. I Edit my question for a better explanation. In this case my menu and submenu change the color for the same if I have diferent colors in menu and submenu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, simply use the hover binding.

```
$("ul li a").bind("hover", function () {
    $(this).css("color", "#FFF");
});
$("ul li").bind("hover", function () {
    $(this).children("a").css("color", "#FFF");
});
```

Note that this code won't reset the CSS properties when you mouse out. To do that you would need to store the original color values.

It is probably worth it to set that `a` element to `display: block` so it expands to the entire parent `li` element. Then you only need to hover on one of them.

Comment: @Josh If it doesn't reset the color after the hover ends, then it is not equivalent to the CSS code, ergo, it is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Sime: I still don't understand why you would want to do this in JS when it can easily be done in CSS.

Comment: @Josh I don't think it can. If you use `css("color", "#FFF")` to set the color, then you cannot use static CSS to supersede that, because CSS rules set via css() have a higher specificity than static CSS.

Comment: @Josh What your code does is: it sets the ANCHOR color to white when it is hovered for the first time, and then that color becomes permanent. The meaning of `:hover` is that the CSS rules apply only while the matched element is hovered.

Comment: @Sime: I understand that, I don't think he's using colors simply looking for a JavaScript `hover` binding. I understand what my code does, hence the disclaimer.

Comment: hello, I edit my question to explain better what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bind a hover function for the li tag. Whenever mouseover/mouseout is on the `<a>` tag the event will bubble up to the `<li>`

```
$(function(){   
    $("ul li").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color", "#fff");
    },function(){
        $(this).css("color", "#000000");
    });
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F7gAG/)

If you can achieve the effect using CSS then why go for javascript solution.

Comment: Both the `a` and parent `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').hover(
    function(){
         $(this).css({color:'white'}); //mouseover
    },
    function(){
         $(this).css({color:'black'}); // mouseout
    }
);
```

Comment: This is not what i want. Thanks